# Can I easily port tcmportmapper to iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have found a cool framework [tcmportmapper](http://code.google.com/p/tcmportmapper/) for mapping the ports over NAT written in Objective-C (as a wrapper framework for some C libraries). I would like to use it in an iOS app, but so far I had little success building it with iOS SDK. Do you know some other framework with similar functionality for iOS or maybe some tips how one can compile a framework written for Cocoa for iOS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I realized the functionality is actually included in the Bonjour libraries and it pretty much comes down to a single function [DNSServiceNATPortMappingCreate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/dns_sd_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/DNSServiceNATPortMappingCreate). Works like charm, so after all no porting will be necessary I guess.

Comment: I'm trying to get TCMportMapper to work on iOS to do port forwarding only. I'm having huge trouble with functions not supported and libraries missing. Did you get this to work ? and if so could you post details, really need it